# How to read XML document which is fixed width?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I got an XML file to load. The problem is that it is physically saved as a fixed width file. This means that the whole is written in lines with a fixed width, with exceptions, i.e. there may be fewer characters in the line.
There are errors when using XmlDocument.Load ().
How to correctly load such an XML file?

This is how the file looks:
[image: This is how the file looks]

Comment: What error you are getting while doing XmlDocument.Load() ?

Comment: First things first: this is not an XML file, so don't call it XML, and don't try to use XML tools to process it. It is a non-XML file, and you need to start by using non-XML tools to convert it to XML.

Comment: If you read the file with string xml = File.ReadAllText(); and then remove all the '\n' characters it should work.  You can use the string replace method and replace "\n" with ""(empty string) : xml = xml.Replace("\n","").  XML does not require the the returns.

Comment: Do you know any non-XML tools to convert it to XML?

Answer (score 1):

Use the file helpers-library from C#
It's free and should solve your problem: https://www.filehelpers.net/

Edit: If you're doing that already it would be good to know the error message you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have to fix the file into the proper format. To be honest, I've seen these particular xmls and I've never seen such occurence. When you download the XML it is already in such format?

I guess, you're creating an XML out of the given XML schema (XSD), at least that's what I was doing with "JPK". What error are you receiving from XmlDocument.Load()?

Comment: I get that kind of file, and it looks like you see. Using XmlDocument.Load throws error about that file is not XML. So the question is, how to convert it to good XML FILE?